# Twitter oauth parameter

Tags: twitter, oauth-php

I'm using [abraham's twitter oauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) and I cannot figure out how to get email parameter, it does not provide a list of parameters. I tried using `$content->{email};` but it returns a blank array, any idea how can I get the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **NO** way you can get email address of a twitter user. Twitter doesn't provide it in their API.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#6718

Comment: Any workaround for it? Like search for email by using screen name, but yet it has limits as twitter gives an option to search by email, but still is there a workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I suggest you check out the twitter documentation starting with https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/search